# How are switch tables updated in a multi-switch network?

Tags: switch

I have a network structure like the below:

```
      Switch A - Switch D
      /      \
 Switch B    Switch C
 /  |  \     /  | \  \
1   2   3   4   5  6  7
```

Where `1..7` are hosts. If `1` were to send a message to `6`, and then `6` responds to `1`, I want to know what each switch switch table looks like.

I have an idea that `B` will have a switch table containing `1`'s host entry, `C` will have `4`'s entry, and `A` will have both, but what about `D`? My thought process is the switch tables are updated when a new frame is received, so when `1` sends a message to `6`, `B` is updated with `1`, `A` is updated with `1`, and likewise `C` and `A` with `6`.

Is `D` empty? I'm not sure how the tables are updated.

Comment: Hrmm, I don't think the linked question is a duplicate question. That explains how a switches MAC address table works, but not exactly / explicitly how it works with multiple switches. I can't post an answer while the question is closed, but to the OP or future readers, this article I wrote explains it:  https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/communication-through-multiple-switches/

Comment: @Eddie in my research, I did find your webpage and it helped immensely. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you found it and glad it helped =)